# Gulp dist folder can't created in my project

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp

I create a project gulp and make css folder in gulp but I can't see folder that I want to create I can't see any error in command line this is my gulp code

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
 var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    console.log('You create a gulp task');
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
   console.log('imagine something')
});

gulp.task('styles', function(){
return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/style.css').pipe(gulp.dest('./app/styles/styles.css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
   watch('./app/index.html', function(){
      gulp.start('html'); 
   });
    watch('./app/assets/styles/**/*.css', function(){
        gulp.start('styles');
    })
});
```

I am using gulp version 3.9.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D04nu.png)

Comment: Try `gulp.dest('./app/styles')`

Comment: Yes, `gulp.dest()` only takes a folder (or a function that returns a folderName) not a fileName as you have.

Comment: A lot of thanks it's working